# memory leak in a fortran program with polymorphism

Tags: memory, fortran, polymorphism

I would like to use some of the F2003 data polymorphism. It was embedded in a code for physics and I observed that memory consumption was increasing until freezing my workstation. I have a compact code where the problem occurs:

```
module functions_defs
  implicit none
  
  type, abstract :: funcroot
    character(len=:),allocatable :: funcname
    contains
      procedure(func), deferred :: eval
  end type funcroot

  interface
    function func(this, x) result(fx)
      import :: funcroot
      class(funcroot),    intent(inout) :: this
      real*8,             intent(in)    :: x
      real*8                            :: fx
    end function func
  end interface     
        
end module functions_defs

module functions
  use functions_defs
  implicit none    

  type, extends(funcroot) :: funcroot1
    real*8 :: a,b
    contains
      procedure :: eval => func1
  end type 

  contains
    function func1(this, x) result(fx)
      class(funcroot1),   intent(inout) :: this
      real*8,             intent(in)    :: x
      real*8                            :: fx
      
      fx=this%a*x*x-this%b

    end function func1
        
end module functions

program testleak
use functions
implicit none
class(funcroot),allocatable :: myfunc

myfunc = funcroot1(a=1.0d0,b=1.0d0,funcname="function1")

end program testleak
```

I am using gfortran 7.5.0. Using valgrind indicates a memory leak, or alternatively bracketting:

```
do
  myfunc = funcroot1(a=1.0d0,b=1.0d0,funcname="function1")
end do
```

top shows increasing memory consumption.

Has anyone any idea why this is happening ?

Many thanks

#### Edit 1

Tested also with ubuntu 22.04 with gfortran 11.3 and mingw gfortran 13.1. Same problem.

#### Edit 2

With intel fortran compiler 2021.9.0, the version with infinite loop does not show increasing memory consumption with the top command. Valgrind still complains about possible lost of bytes.

#### Edit 3

I slightly modified the code in order to avoid the explicit declaration and allocation of myfunc (and also removed real*8):

```
module utils
  use, intrinsic    :: iso_fortran_env
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: rp = REAL64            
end module utils 

module functions_defs
  use utils
  implicit none
  
  type, abstract :: funcroot
    character(len=:), allocatable :: funcname
    contains
      procedure(func), deferred :: eval
  end type funcroot

  interface
    function func(this, x) result(fx)
      import :: funcroot,rp
      class(funcroot), intent(inout) :: this
      real(kind=rp),   intent(in)    :: x
      real(kind=rp)                  :: fx
    end function func
  end interface     
        
end module functions_defs

module functions
  use functions_defs
  implicit none    

  type, extends(funcroot) :: funcroot1
    real(kind=rp) :: a,b
    contains
      procedure :: eval => func1
  end type 

  contains
    function func1(this, x) result(fx)
      class(funcroot1), intent(inout) :: this
      real(kind=rp),    intent(in)    :: x
      real(kind=rp)                   :: fx
      
      fx=this%a*x*x-this%b

    end function func1
        
end module functions

module print
  use functions
  implicit none

  contains
    subroutine printf(f)
      class(funcroot) :: f
      
      write(*,*) "Function: "//trim(f%funcname)

    end subroutine printf    
end module print

program testleak
use print
implicit none

do 
  call printf(funcroot1(a=1.0_rp,b=1.0_rp,funcname="function1"))
end do  

end program testleak
```

This code runs flawlessly with gfortran 7.5 and valgrind.

Comment: Looks like a bug, or at least an implementation issue. gfortran 7 is 4 years old, could you test with a recent version?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tested with gfortran 11.3 and the issue remains

Comment: Do not use `real*8` in a modern code, it hurts to see this.

Comment: I usually do not, I just wanted to extract a quick example from a bigger code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I have compiled and run your code (with an infinite do loop) with ifort 19, I can see no leakage. So it really looks like an implementation issue in gfortran.

Comment: @PierU I confirm that using latest intel compiler 2021.9.0, memory consumption stays constant. Valgrind however still complains with possibly lost bytes.

Comment: The `myfunc` object is not explicitely deallocated before the end of the program, that's maybe what valgrind complains about.

Comment: @PierU It turns out that adding a `deallocate(myfunc)` right after `myfunc = funcroot1(a=1.0d0,b=1.0d0,funcname="function1")` makes things worse with valgrind. In this case I get bytes definitely lost

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I modified the code to avoid real*8 and the declaration of myfunc, see EDIT 3. In this case everything seems to work. So you both think it is a bug with gfortran ?

Comment: It is quite clear, I see no other reason for a leak. You can try valgrind with track originals to see some details.